# I want to cancel an alarm created from other activity in Android

Tags: android

I have the problem removing the alarm which I already set. I used two activities to "ADD" or "EDIT" alarms. When I delete an alarm, I want to use the activity which is made to show list of alarms. However, It doesn't delete the PendingIntent I set.

Here's the part of my source code in List Activity.

```
private void removeAlarm(int number)
{
    final int alarmCode = AlarmCodeCreator.CreateNum(1, clickedPosition, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListMainActivity.this,
            PushMainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), alarmCode, intent, 0);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    System.out.println(alarmCode);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag and make sure to create the PendingIntent the same way it was originally created.
Same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android).