# Delete Alarm with a unique ID

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I do have a NoteApp, where you can set reminder.

I want to implement that you can cancel the alarm.

My problem is I cant find any tutorial how to do this.

I've set an unique ID and saved it into the SQLite Database.

So when I click on Dialog "Yes" it should cancel the Alarm.

Here I set the alarm:

```
Intent i = new Intent(NeueNotiz.this,NoteNotification.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(NeueNotiz.this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),i,0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                                isAlarmSet(true,String.valueOf(cal_new.getTimeInMillis()));

                                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal_new.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

I have absolutely no clue.
Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
    SessionReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, myIntent, 0);

 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

See [How to cancel alarm from AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922521/how-to-cancel-alarm-from-alarmmanager) link for more info.