# How to cancel alarm set with setAlarmClock() Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, setalarmclock

How can I cancel an alarm set with setAlarmClock()?

```
val alarmReceiver = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
val alarmReceiverPi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, alarmReceiver, 0)

val alarmInfo = AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(time, alarmReceiverPi)

alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmInfo, alarmReceiverPi)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` to used to locate the `PendingIntent`, following is my example:

```
fun setAlarm() {
    val alarmPendingIntent = getAlarmPendingIntent(alarmId)

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, _timeLong.value, alarmPendingIntent)

    showToast("Alarm has been set")
}

fun cancelAlarm() {
    val alarmPendingIntent = getAlarmPendingIntent(alarmId)

    alarmManager.cancel(alarmPendingIntent) 

    showToast("Alarm has bee canceled")
}

private fun getAlarmPendingIntent(id: Long): PendingIntent {
    val intent = Intent(getApplication(), AlarmReceiver::class.java)

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(), id.toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)  //will override if same id
}
```

- Helpful reading:
  [How to cancel alarm from AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922521/how-to-cancel-alarm-from-alarmmanager)

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem was that I used different request codes.