# Android alarm not cancelling

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am in the main activity. There is a **Login** button `bLogin`. When it is pressed, a **Logout** button is displayed `bLogout`. The `onClick` methods for the two buttons are as follows:

```
bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        llLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 327,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    }
});

bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        llLogout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 327,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 327,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        if(!alarmUp){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

As can be seen in the code above, when `bLogin` is pressed, I set the alarm, and when `bLogout` is pressed, I cancel the alarm.

`alarmUp` is used to check if the alarm is set. But the problem is that the alarm is never cancelled because the `Toast` at the end is never displayed. Also, the work that should be done by the app when the alarm is not set is never done on pressing **Logout**.

I can't seem to figure out what might be wrong. The `PendingIntent`s are the same for both when the alarm is set, and when it is cancelled.

Comment: i hope it would be better for you look up this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android

Comment: I have already seen that. I don't see what I have missed in that post. You mind pointing it out? Thanks!

Comment: Your code to cancel the alarm looks ok.  Just to note, that method of checking if an alarm is set is flaky, and it will actually only return false if you call `cancel()` on the PendingIntent in addition to cancelling the alarm.

Comment: @DanielNugent So, do you know any better way of doing what I am trying to do?

Comment: @DanielNugent I am cancelling the pendingIntent. So what do you mean by cancelling the alarm? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what's wrong with your code, but if you want to cancel the pending intent you can use

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 327, pendingIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

to cancel the pending intent. I think it'll do the same think as cancelling your AlarmManager. Although you might need to change the way you check the way your alarm is set.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't cancelling the `PendingIntent`. When you call

```
manager.cancel(pendingIntent)
```

you are cancelling the alarm. This doesn't cancel the `PendingIntent`. The `PendingIntent` still exists. So when you then call

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 327,
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

the `PendingIntent` still exists, so `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` will return a non-null. result. `alarmUp` will always be `true`.

You need to cancel the `PendingIntent` after you cancel the alarm, like this:

```
pendingIntent.cancel();
```

Comment: Great!!! Cancelling pending intent is perfect solution compare to manager. Did upvote