# Stopping an Alarm from a different Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Okay, it goes like this; DeviceListActivity initiates an alarm. Then, AlarmReceiver creates an activity which is called AlarmActivity to do some work and stop the alarm and terminate itself. But I could not manage to stop the alarm. My codes are given below.

DeviceListActivity:

```
public void startAlarm(View view) {
    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    calNow.set(Calendar.SECOND, calNow.get(Calendar.SECOND) + 1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calNow.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
    Intent alarmActivity = new Intent();
    alarmActivity.setClassName(context.getPackageName(),AlarmActivity.class.getName());
    alarmActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(alarmActivity);
}
```

AlarmActivity:

```
public void stopAlarm(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: didn't find any problem in your code. try just replace "getBaseContext()" to "this"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed all the "getBaseContext()" calls to "this" but alarm still continues.

Comment: hey.. I got this.. cancel also the pending intent. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30895383/1263362

Comment: I was also excited but nope :(

Comment: how do you know the alarm is not canceled?

Answer (score -1):

In the Alarm Activity, try this code:

```
public void stopAlarm(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// add this if condition to check and cancel the alarm if AlarmManager is not null
if (alarmManager!= null) {
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think, a NullPointerException would be thrown if the alarmManager was null. There is no exception thrown in my case. I tried your code but the alarm did not stop.