# Android skip alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

my question is how can I skip an alarm in Android.

I have created an alarm with a one-day interval. But the user can press a button to do the automatical work which is done after the interval, by himself.

So on the same day the automatical work shouldn`t be done again. But on the next day the alarm interval should work as before.

Can I handle this with the cancel-method? I think no. I think the cancel-method will cancel the whole alarm and not cancel only the next alarm.

How can I do it?

I hope you understand me. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); that should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your `alarmId` somewhere, when user completes his task all my himself than cancel your alarm by using your saved `alarmId`

For more details see [Delete alarm from AlarmManager using cancel() - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android)

Comment: I have this code in my programm...

     Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

Is it normal that the id is at first 1. And when the Service get called at second time 2 and at the third time 3. Or is this maybe the problem in my code?
My problem is that the alarm never get canceled. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

When the user presses the button to do whatever work manually, you should have it cancel your alarm all together and then restart a new alarm with this in your calendar start time object:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

That will make the alarm start at whatever time you already set, but  not until the **next** day.  As long as you reinstate your alarm with the same interval it will go back to working normal and will not fire off on the current day.