# Cancel alarm set by SetAlarmClock

Tags: android, setalarmclock

I create an alarm using `AlarmManager.setAlarmClock(AlarmClockInfo, pendingIntent)` and it works. The System also displays an alarm clock on the top-right part of the screen.

So far, so good, but how can I cancel that alarm? I tried using `AlarmManager.cancel()` but the icon on the top-right is still there. Any idea?
Let's say the user doesn't want to scheduler the task anymore, so the icon should be gone.....

HINT: Cancel() seems to cancel alarms created by Set, SetExact, SetAllowWhileIdle... and all those. But here I am talking about setAlarmClock() which is a different story.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete alarm from AlarmManager using cancel() - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android)

Comment: Not duplicate. Your link cancels alarms created by setAlarm not by setAlarmClock

Comment: ever found a solution?