# Android button to stop alarm is not working?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an alarm to be included in a bigger project. Everything is working correctly with the datepicker/timepicker. And the alarm does start once the date and time has been reached. The problem i am having is the only way to stop the alarm is by closing the application. I have added a button (stopAlarm) with everything i thought would be needed to stop this pending intent, but it is still not stopping the alarm?

I am probably overlooking something very small but i was wondering if there is anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

**MainActivity:**

```
package servicealarmdemo.test2;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

DatePicker pickerDate;
TimePicker pickerTime;
Button buttonSetAlarm;
Button buttonStopAlarm;
TextView info;

final static int RQS_1 = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    pickerDate = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);
    pickerTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickertime);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    pickerDate.init(
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            null);

    pickerTime.setCurrentHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    pickerTime.setCurrentMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    buttonSetAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
    buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
                    pickerDate.getMonth(),
                    pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
                    00);

            if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){
                //The set Date/Time already passed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Date/Time Has Already Passed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                setAlarm(cal);
            }

            buttonStopAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopalarm);
            buttonStopAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        }});

}


private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    info.setText("\n\n***\n"
            + "Deadline has now been set: " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
            + "***\n");

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}

}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java:**

```
package servicealarmdemo.test2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, uri);
    ringtone.play();
}
}
```

**XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/pickerdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/pickertime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setalarm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set Alarm"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopalarm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="stopAlarm"
            android:text="Stop Alarm"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a different mechanism to connect your methods with the view - setAlarm is with code (onClickListener) and stopAlarm is with XML.  It could be a problem with the way the XML is connecting to the view/Activity, or a problem in the stopAlarm method itself.  Put some debugging in the stopAlarm method to confirm it is getting called.

Also, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android), you may need to use the "CURRENT_UPDATE_FLAG" when getting the pending intent.

```
public void stopAlarm(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

}
```

One other thing to try is caching the intent between set and stop alarm.  Rather than re-creating the intent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i changed the stopAlarm method to match setAlarm using an (onClickListener). Also updated the code using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT but nothing happens when i press the stop alarm button. The alarm continues to fire.

Comment: @ZenoX Did you put some debugging?  is stopAlarm getting called?

Comment: @ZenoX try keeping a reference to the intent and re-using it instead of creating a new intent.  There could be something different about it even though I can't see anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will continue to look into it. I am sure i am missing something, i just can't figure out what.