# Stop schedule on a given time

Tags: android, sqlite

i am developing a scheduling app in which user selects a time from listview like 9:30 P.M or any time which is in the list and hits the button stop schedule, what i want want to stop schedule at 9:30 when its 9:30 (i will cal  update method in database and update the user end time) or which the user selects from the list, user can also stop multiple schedules at a same time, i tried to use Scheduling Repeating Alarms but did not find any solution.
Please help me how can i do this?.

This is code i am making alarm for specific time

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void scheduleAlarm(View view, String timeEnd,String id) {

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(timeEnd, ":");
    String first = tokens.nextToken();
    String second = tokens.nextToken();

    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(second, " ");
    String two = token.nextToken(); // just changing given time into like 9:30 to 9 and 30

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    android.icu.util.Calendar calendar = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(android.icu.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(first));
    calendar.set(android.icu.util.Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(two));

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
    intent.putExtra("ID",id);
    intent.putExtra("EndTime",timeEnd);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

}
```

And this is the Broadcast Receiver its works but broadcast class trigger at same time when i give the time to alarm schedule not on the given time.

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SQLITEDBTABLE sqLiteDatabase = new SQLITEDBTABLE(context);

    String id = intent.getStringExtra("ID");
    String time_end = intent.getStringExtra("EndTime");

    sqLiteDatabase.update(time_end, id);
   /* sqLiteDatabase.deleteOlderData(laterId);
    sqLiteDatabase.deleteInactive(laterId);
    sqLiteDatabase.updateEmployee(laterId, "Inactive");*/
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered and SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, can I have a look at your code snippet?

Comment: do you want me to upload the code?

Comment: Yes...only the part that contains your scheduling code

Comment: please see the code

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

From the code..... `Calendar.getInstance()` is already up to date. So you have.

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    public void scheduleAlarm(View view, String timeEnd,String id) {

        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(timeEnd, ":");
        String first = tokens.nextToken();
        String second = tokens.nextToken();

        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(second, " ");
        String two = token.nextToken(); // just changing given time into like 9:30 to 9 and 30

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        android.icu.util.Calendar calendar = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(android.icu.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(first));
        calendar.set(android.icu.util.Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(two));

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID",id);
        intent.putExtra("EndTime",timeEnd);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Comment: same problem alarm triggers same time when i tried to stop schedule at a different time

Comment: How are you cancelling the alarm?

Comment: i am just calling this function scheduleAlarm() on schedule stop button listview adapter by giving two parameters timeEnd and Id.

Comment: checkout how to cancel alarm here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android

Comment: i dont want to cancel the alarm i just want Broadcast class call on the given time to alarm.

Comment: Please note that the time is usually in 24 hrs... so 9:30 pm according to your code is actually 9:30 am instead of 21:30 ... also note that, if the time you set has passed , say the current time is 9:40 am and you schedule 9:30 am for the same day, the alarm manager will be triggered immediately