# manager.Cancel(PendingIntent) does't work for me in Xamarin Android

Tags: android-intent, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

```
## Cancel Pending Intents ##

 private void Alarm_off_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnAlaramStop();
    }
    public void OnAlaramStop()
    {
         Intent myint = new Intent();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
        PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, 0, myint, 
        PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        alarm_manager.Cancel(pendingIntent);

    }
```

I create multiple Pending Intents, that wake-up my device at specific time, but i wants that , when i click the Alaram_Off Button , then all the pending Intents Cancel. But Unfortunately pending Intents are not cancelled.
Who will help me, Thanks in advance all my dears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `OnDestroy` to name your custom method, because it already exits in both `Activity` and `Service`. Just change `OnDestory` to `OnAlaramStop`, like this:

```
public void OnAlaramStop()
{
    alarm_manager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
    pendingIntent.Cancel();

}
```

Comment: [Please refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485368/delete-alarm-from-alarmmanager-using-cancel-android), you need use [PendingIntentFlags](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.PendingIntentFlags/)

Comment: Sir , PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent is working here, but actually i want to Cancel Completely all the Pending Intents, So i change my Code as above ,but not working still,i don't know ???????

Comment: Above your code, add `pendingIntent.Cancel();` in your `OnAlaramStop()` method. Did you forgot it?

Comment: I change the Intent as above, and start work perfect for me , thank you very much